# How to save data from result where eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to save data returned from 'where' eloquent laravel.

My code:

```
public function duplicate_save(Request $request){
            $this->validate($request, [
                'bulan_from' => 'required',
                'tahun_from' => 'required',
                'bulan_to' => 'required',
                'tahun_to' => 'required',
            ]);

            $realisasi_keuangan = RealisasiKeuangan::where('bulan', $request->bulan_from)->where('tahun', $request->tahun_from)->get();

            RealisasiKeuangan::create($realisasi_keuangan);

            return redirect()->route('apps.realisasi-keuangan.index');
        }
```

But the code return error

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create(): Argument #1 ($attributes) must be of type array, App\Models\RealisasiKeuangan given
```

Comment: have you tried `toArray()` ?

Comment: Notice that when you use a get method on any builder in Laravel , it will return you collection object , so you need to cast it to an array to solve your problem .